# Flot Chart Value Labels with multiple axes

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to do a Flot multiline (with multiple y axes) with labels in all values, but I can't do it...

My code is:

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder-bar-chart" class="mychart"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var d1 = [[1456531200000,14.46],[1456704000000,11.07],[1456790400000,13.12],[1456876800000,10.8],[1457049600000,16.51]];

var d2 = [[1456617600000,"1"]];

var data1 = [
{
    label: "Values",
     yaxis: 1,
    data: d1  
}, {
    label: "Events",
    data: d2,
     yaxis: 2,
    points: {show: true, 
        radius: 6}

}];
var ticks = [[0,""],[1, "Event1"],[2, "Event2"],[3, "Event3"]];

var p = $.plot($("#placeholder-bar-chart"), data1, {
xaxis: { 
    mode: "time",
    tickSize: [1, "day"],
    tickLength: 0, 
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
    axisLabelPadding: 5
},
yaxes: [
 {
    position: "left",
    color: "black",
},
{
 position: "right",
    ticks: ticks,
    color: "black",
}], 

grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: false,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor:'#f0f0f0',
    labelMargin:8,
},
 legend: {
    show: true,
    noColumns: 2
}   
});

$.each(p.getData()[0].data, function(i, el){
var o = p.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1]});
$('<div class="data-point-label">' + el[1] + '</div>').css( {
position: 'absolute',
left: o.left + 4,
top: o.top - 43,
display: 'none'
}).appendTo(p.getPlaceholder()).fadeIn('slow');
});

$.each(p.getData()[1].data, function(i, el){
var o = p.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1]});
$('<div class="data-point-label">' + el[1] + '</div>').css( {
position: 'absolute',
left: o.left + 4,
top: o.top - 43,
display: 'none'
}).appendTo(p.getPlaceholder()).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

And I get this graphic:

[image]

It would be possible to put the labels on all points? 
I'd like to put on events values the corresponding tick label.

http://jsfiddle.net/gaia/8v55wzjc/117/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the yaxis for which the coordinates are calculated in the `pointOffset` function like described in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods). For the event label(s) use:

```
var o = p.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1], yaxis: 2});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v55wzjc/118/).

Comment: And, it would be possible that instead of "1" on blue point, it would be "Event1"??

Comment: Yes, replace the `el[1]` in the content of the label div with the corresponding name from the `ticks` array.

Comment: Thank you! I did: http://jsfiddle.net/8v55wzjc/119/ but I got 2 values on point...

Comment: `ticks[1]` is an array, use `ticks[1][1]` to get only the name. But beware, this only works as long as the first value (here 1) is the same as the index in the ticks array.

Comment: Ah, ok. So, if I had more "Events"?? It would be possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, you just need a function to get the event name for a number from the `ticks` array, for example by using a for loop.